# Stored-procedures mysql return null when I execute that

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to execute this PL/Mysql to get 3 values in return but

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE p_login(user VARCHAR(16), 
pass VARCHAR(30),
OUT Tipo_usuarios VARCHAR(1), 
OUT estado_usuarios VARCHAR(1),
OUT idUsuarios INT(11)) 
BEGIN
    DECLARE s_tipo,  s_estado VARCHAR(1);
    DECLARE s_id INT(11);
    SELECT Tipo_usuarios, estado_usuarios, idUsuarios 
    INTO s_tipo, s_estado, s_id
    FROM USUARIOS
    WHERE 
        user_usuarios = user AND
        pass_usuarios = pass;
    IF s_id IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET Tipo_usuarios = s_tipo;
        SET estado_usuarios = s_estado;
        SET idUsuarios = s_id;
        INSERT INTO BITACORA_LOGIN (usuario_bitacora, 
        fecha_bitacora) 
        VALUES (s_id, SYSDATE(), USER());
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

when I execute

```
CALL p_login('user1', 597293, @a, @b, @c);
SELECT @a, @b, @c;
```

I always get **NULL** values, any Idea about how to execute or what is bad in my PL/Mysql?

Comment: Never ever use variables that have the same name as a column in your tables (in this case: your OUT-parameters). You won't get happy. (Additional note: do not use `commit` without starting a transaction.)

Comment: Thanks! for your help, I remember that in ORACLE PL/SQL I have `EXCEPTION` and something like `when other then` what is the most similar in MYSLQ?